# Playwright Python - Record video the newly opened page

Tags: python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I'm new to playwright automation and using Python. I'm stuck at recording video after a new page( opened in same window as new tab) is opened. The video is only showing for the first tab.

```
def test_perform_actions_and_record():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        # Launch the browser and open example.com in the first page
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context(record_video_dir="videos/")
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("https://example.com")

        # Open a new tab (a new page within the same context)
        new_page = context.new_page()

        context = browser.new_context(record_video_dir="videos/")
        page = context.new_page()
        # Go to example2.com in the new tab
        new_page.goto("https://example2.com")

        # Perform actions on the new tab
        new_page.fill("#username", "example_user")
        new_page.fill("#password", "example_password")
        new_page.click("#login_button")

        # Continue with other interactions on the new tab

        # Close both pages and the context when done
        page.close()
        new_page.close()
        context.close()

        # Close the browser
        browser.close()
```

Please suggest how to continuously record or even if there is a way to start recording on the new tab opened.

In my use-case the new tab is opened as a result for an action in the first page (The above is only a sample script to explain my problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what is your page, but actually this is done automatically by playwright.

Here you have an example:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(record_video_dir="videos/")
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://twitter.com/")

    # With following 3 lines we are expecting a new page to be open.
    # Once the event of new page is fired, we catch that page and we save in new_page_info.
    with context.expect_page() as new_page_info:
        page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
        page.click("//span[text()='Cookie Policy']")  # Opens a new tab
    # Once we have the event of new page, we get the attribute "value", which is the actual page
    new_page = new_page_info.value
    new_page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
```

We are navigating to twitter, clicking on Cookie and policy link (Which is open in a new tab) and then we just wait.

In your folder /videos, you should be able to see 2 videos, one for the first page and another one for the second page.